# Linear Independent proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

In my Linear Algebra class we define Linear dependence as follows:

If  $F$ is a field and $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$. The set $A = {\lbrace v_1,v_2,...,v_k \rbrace}$  where $v_1,v_2,...,v_k \in V $ is linearly dependent if $\exists$ a linear combination:

$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + ... +a_k v_k = 0$ where $ a_1, a_2 ,...,a_k\in F$

such that not all of the coefficients are zero

Then we are told to verify the following:

a set $A =  {\lbrace v_1,v_2,...,v_k \rbrace}$  is linearly independent if and only if  $a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + ... +a_k v_k = 0 $
$\Rightarrow a_1=a_2=...=a_k =0$

**Note:**
I know that some textbooks use this as a definition  of linear independence. We have not defined linear independence at all.

In my opinion the proof is trivial in both directions, However I am concerned that what I have in mind is not rigorous enough.

**My Idea/Attempt:**

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $A$ is linearly independent then by the converse of the definition above there can not exist a set of coefficients where not all of  them are zero.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $\exists$ a set of coefficients $\lbrace a_1,a_2,...,a_k\rbrace  $ such that $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+..a_kv_k =0 $ if some $a_i \neq 0 $ then of course  $A$  is linearly dependent

What do you think of my idea?

Comment: I suggest you post what you have in mind, and then we can comment on it.

Comment: I imagine that you are supposed to take the definition that a set of vectors is linearly independent if it is not linearly dependent?

Comment: @hmmmm I think that is the idea.

Comment: @Calle What do you think?

Comment: Well, "the converse of the definition" is a slightly odd phrase (a definition is not an implication). Just say "if not all of the coefficients are zero, this would be a contradiction". It would probably also be good to explicitly state that you take "linearly independent" to mean "not linearly dependent". The $\Rightarrow$ direction could be made clearer by stating that you prove the contrapositive (there exists $a_i$, not all zero, hence linearly dependent).

Comment: Thanks @Calle for the constructive critiscm

Comment: But these are just small details, I think you seem to have gotten the idea right.

Comment: @Calle and the $\Leftarrow$ That is one am less sure about

Comment: Okay, this is how I probably would put it. Suppose $A$ is not linearly dependent. Then for any $\{a_i\}_i$ such that $\sum a_i v_i = 0$ we must have $a_i = 0$ for all $i$, since if this was not the case, $A$ would be linearly dependent by the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\textrm{$A$ is linearly independent}$$
$$ \textrm{if and only if}$$
$$ \textrm{$A$ is NOT linearly dependent}$$
$$\textrm{if and only if}$$
$$\neg(\exists a_1\ldots\exists a_k(a_i\neq 0 \textrm{ some i } \wedge a_1v_1+\ldots +a_kv_k=0))$$ 
$$\textrm{if and only if}$$
$$\forall a_1\ldots a_k ( \forall i (a_i=0) \vee a_1v_1+\ldots +a_kv_k\neq 0))$$
$$\textrm{ if and only if}$$
$$\forall a_1\ldots a_k (a_1v_1+\ldots +a_kv_k=0\rightarrow \forall i(a_i=0))$$

Comment: Beautiful. Simple and elegant.